# Ler os dados do PHP no Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Sou programador novato tanto em PHP quanto em Javascript e estou com uma dúvida em um projeto que estou desenvolvendo.

Eu tenho um servidor conectado a um arquivo PHP e estou requisitando os seguintes campos

```
$FLD="idfca, solfca";
```

Eu criei uma função dentro do Javascript para carregar meus registros, de 10 em 10, com o scroll:

```js
    var contador = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    carregar();
    $(this).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(this).height()) {
            carregar();
        }
    });
});

function carregar() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $("#lista").append('<li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/><div><h4>' + contador + ' Item</h4><p>Descrição do item '+contador+'</p></div></li>');
        contador++;
    }
}
```

O que quero saber é como utilizar os campos que estou puxando do banco dentro desta função em javascript, no lugar do contador.

Comment: Amigo, utilize a tecnologia `Ajax` para pegar os dados vindos do PHP. E, no PHP, você responde esses dados como `JSON`. É só utilizar a função  json_encode :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Ajax está mais para técnica não?

Comment: @durtto sei lá, estou confuso até hoje, mas perguntei sobre isso aqui.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116153/ajax-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ent%C3%A3o-o-que-%C3%A9

Answer (score 2):

Uma aplicação web possui, simplificadamente, 3 elementos: cliente, servidor e persistência.

No lado do cliente, utiliza-se Javascript em praticamente todos os casos. No servidor, utiliza-se PHP, por exemplo. E na persistência um SGBD qualquer, como o MySQL e o PostgreSQL.

O Javascript não consegue conversar diretamente com o SGBD, mas ele consegue realizar requisições ao servidor web (implementado em PHP, por exemplo) através de Ajax (nada mais que requisições HTTP disparadas por um Javascript).

O PHP por sua vez, através dos *drivers*, consegue se comunicar com o SGBD.

Portanto, o que você terá que fazer é realizar uma requisição Ajax dentro do seu comando Javascript `carregar` para o seu servidor. Nesta requisição, as informações pertinentes devem ser passadas, como quais campos a serem retornados, intervalo dos resultados retornados, etc. Em PHP, por sua vez, você irá interpretar a requisição e enviar comandos SQL para o MySQL a fim de gerar a resposta para a requisição.

Uma vez que o MySQL retorne os dados, o melhor é formatá-los como um Json através da função `json_encode` do PHP e enviar estes dados como resposta da sua requisição Ajax (algo como `echo json_encode($dados);`). A vantagem disto, é que o Json será interpretado pelo browser e você poderá acessá-lo como um objeto, facilitando sua manipulação.

Por fim, sua função `carregar` terá os dados necessários para preencher a página, bastando gerar os elementos e preenchê-los com as informações que acabaram de ser retornadas.

Note que existem várias tarefas a serem realizadas. Apresentei, em linhas gerais, o que deve acontecer para que você consiga obter os dados desejados e apresentá-los ao cliente. Agora você deve estudar as tecnologias citadas, e aplicá-las na solução do seu problema.