# AJAX não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?

Tags: ajax, terminologia

Estou fazendo esta pergunta porque eu já cansei de ver coisas como requisitos para determinado cargo de programação:

> É necessários saber as linguagens PHP, JavaScript, CSS e **AJAX**

Já aprendi que AJAX não é uma linguagem de programação (é claro, porque ninguém "programa em AJAX").

Mas, tratando-se da questão dos termos, como deveríamos classificar o AJAX? Recurso? Tecnologia? Como deveria ser denominado?

Comment: O trecho citado é de uma vaga de emprego?

Comment: @rray como sempre, os anúncios de vaga de emprego sempre mitando.

Comment: Qual é o certo, então ? "É necessário saber digitar em Ajax" ou "É necessário saber as bibliotecas Ajax, jQuery..."...

Comment: @Zoom Eu diria que AJAX é uma **técnica**. Para usar esta técnica, você precisa conhecer a API XMLHttpRequest, JavaScript e DOM, e também o conceito de se buscar informações em background, de maneira assíncrona, e atualizar apenas partes da página sem precisar recarregar a página inteira. Também há frameworks que abstraem a maneira de usar Ajax (usando Java JSF, por exemplo, você usa Ajax escrevendo apenas tags Facelets, sem precisar escrever JavaScript ou interagir diretamente com XMLHttpRequest e o DOM).

Comment: @Caffé é isso mesmo, está absolutamente correto, é uma técnica ou maneira de usar o XMLHttpRequest!

Comment: Acredito eu que o termo AJAX é o que hoje denomina-se SPA (Single Page Application). Entendo assim quando vejo como requisito "Programação AJAX", ou seja, que será necessário saber programar um sistema que usa muito JS, e não apenas linguagem server-side com constantes refreshes.

Comment: @lucasDotCom acho que está confundindo, o ajax não precisa ser usado pra carregar uma página ou atualizar uma página, ele é usado para funções como buscar notificações, mensagens em chats e enviar dados, mas não quer dizer que o site todo vai ser baseado em Ajax, muitas vezes usamos ele apenas em uma funcionalidade especifica. O que podemos dizer é que o SPA faz uso do Ajax, mas não o contrário.

Comment: Guilherme. Na verdade eu não quis dizer isso. Quando vejo "Programação AJAX" como requisito, eu imagino que não seja só pra fazer uma requisição pra buscar uma notificação, buscar uma mensagem, um Long Polling ou uma requisição disparada por evento. Sim, isso é AJAX, mas me referi como requisito de vaga e não como conceito. Um SPA é muito mais complexo dó que só uma requisição simples. Enfim, parece um pouco confuso, pois acabei não me expressando direito.

Comment: [É a nova feature do PHP](https://vidadeprogramador.com.br/2018/08/09/nova-feature/) hahahahaha

Answer (score 47, accepted):

O *AJAX* é uma "maneira" de se usar o [*XmlHttpRequest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), que não é uma linguagem, mas sim uma **API** do JavaScript, assim como [*File API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), [*DOM API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), etc.

O que o XHR ([*XmlHttpRequest API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)) faz é uma comunicação de cliente e servidor, não quer dizer que ele é assíncrono, já o AJAX é a maneira de usar XHR "assincronamente".

Exemplo de XHR síncrono (isto não é AJAX):

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Defina como false
oReq.open("GET", "/url", false);

//Espera completar a requisição, geralmente congela o browser
oReq.send(null);

alert(oReq.responseText);
```

Exemplo de XHR assíncrono (isto é AJAX):

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Defina como true
oReq.open("GET", "/url", true);

//Função assíncrona que aguarda a resposta
oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
        alert(oReq.responseText);
    }
};

//Envia a requisição, mas a resposta fica sendo aguardada em Background
oReq.send(null);
```

Então Ajax significa ***A**synchronous **J**avaScript **a**nd **X**ML* (que traduzindo é JavaScript e XML assíncronos) e é a maneira de se usar o XHR que o torna AJAX ou não. O termo AJAX seria um apelido para o o XHR usado de modo assíncrono.

É importante notar que o modo síncrono foi "apelidado" de SJAX, que significa ***S**ynchronous **J**avaScript **a**nd **X**ML* (JavaScript e XML síncronos)), mas note também que o SJAX está em desuso e os navegadores modernos tem começado a emitir *warnings* no console e provavelmente virão a "bloquear" esta maneira, no entanto dentro de [*Web Workers*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API), pois roda em uma "thread" separada, assim como a mensagem de erro afirma:

> synchronous xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated

Ou seja só no *main thread*, que se refere a thread principal que executa na aba, o *Web Works* executam em sub-threads, o que não causa problema e neste caso não esta em desuso.

Mais detalhes em https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning

Outra situação é que nem sempre usamos XML, mas na época que o apelido surgiu era bastante usado por ter suporte ao `.resposeXML` do XHR, pra usar JSON hoje podemos fazer o `parse` do `.responseText` com algo como:

```
var resposta = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);

console.log(resposta);
```

Ou pode ajustar a propriedade [`XMLHttpRequest.responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) para o "json" e usar o `XMLHttpRequest.response` para obter o JSON, isto supondo que a resposta do servidor seja de fato JSON, ficando algo como:

```
oReq.responseType = "json";

var resposta = oReq.response;

console.log(oReq.response);
```

---

### Callback e assíncrono em JavaScript/ECMAScript

Para entender um pouco melhor sobre como corre os callbacks, dê uma lida em:

- [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635)

Comment: Tome um _insta-up_ ™ pelo bom complemento. +1

Comment: Na verdade significa então que o protagonista é a API XHR, então AJAX é só um termo usado por alguém, que de certa forma tornou mais conhecido o termo abstraído do que é própria tecnologia o XHR , tipo isso né? Ou existe algo no AJAX que pode ser usado sem o XHR ? @rray

Comment: @MagicHat Ajax é isso, usar o XHR de maneira assincrona, qualquer outra coisa sem xhr não é Ajax ;)

Answer (score 25):

AJAX(Asynchronous Javascript and XML) é uma tecnica que utiliza javascript para enviar requisições assincronas a um servidor, tornando páginas e sistemas web(da época e de hoje) mais interativos.

O termo foi cunha por [Jesse James Garrett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_James_Garrett) em 2005 no artigo [Ajax: A New Approach to Web Applications](http://adaptivepath.org/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications/)

Comment: Eu não diria "conjunto de tecnologias" porque basicamente você precisa de JavaScript, DOM e da API XMLHttpRequest, sendo que os dois primeiros são componentes comuns da web e estão presentes também onde o Ajax não está.

Comment: @Caffé obrigado pelo comentário, editei a resposta tem mais alguma sugestão, está de acordo agora?

Comment: Pra mim parece correto.

Comment: @Caffé valeu pelo retorno, não custa nada dar um reformulada :)

Comment: O link para o artigo está quebrado. :/

Answer (score 18):

Para implementar a interface web do Exchange (OWA) sem usar troca de páginas para carregar novo conteúdo, a Microsoft criou uma interface no seu componente MSXML que permitia enviar uma solicitação por HTTP e receber uma resposta assíncrona. Na época o que bombava era XML e a interface foi batizada XMLHttpRequest, mas ela não obriga de forma alguma que o conteúdo retornado seja XML.

Outros desenvolvedores de browsers adotaram a interface e ela explodiu quando a Google lançou o Google Maps. Mais tarde foi empacotada no JQuery o que facilitou muito o seu uso a portabilidade entre browsers.

Então, respondendo a pergunta, acho que AJAX é melhor qualificado como uma **técnica** do que como uma **tecnologia**. Certamente não é uma linguagem de programação. A tecnologia seria a interface para requisições assíncronas, que os browsers originalmente não suportavam.

A história completa está na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#History_and_support), como sempre.

Comment: Definitivamente eu não entendi como é que negativaram essa resposta.

Comment: Não fui eu que dei o -1, porém a parte histórica pode ser melhor clarificada. XMLHttpRequest foi adotado como padrão, porém as primeiras implementações AJAX utilizavam IFRAME para troca de dados: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: @lbotinelly ah sim, dá pra melhorar um bocado. Mas eu acho estranho o negativo, pq além de responder, já deu uma contextualizada. Entenderia a pessoa não votar, mas o fato de negativarem me deixou curioso pra entender o motivo.

Comment: @Bacco os downvoters ladram, a caravana passa. =)

Comment: +1 por "técnica"

Answer (score 14):

AJAX (do inglês ***A***synchronous **Ja**vaScript and **X**ML, ou Javascript e XML assíncrono) é um termo utilizado para práticas de comunicação assíncrona entre uma aplicação web e um back-end correspondente.

Nesta definição, AJAX é um *protocolo* (no sentido em que define um comportamento para troca de dados), sua implementação um *canal* (onde requisições são feitas e respostas recebidas) e sua utilização uma *prática* (requisições assíncronas e seu tratamento).

Answer (score 14):

Sendo mais Especifico a Pergunta:

> AJAX é um **Recurso** do JavaScript.

Na qual você pode :

- Atualizar a página web sem recarregar a página
- Enviar dados a um servidor - após a página já ser carregada.
- Receber dados de um servidor - após a página já ser carregada.

Answer (score 4):

É um método ou processo para utilizar Javascript e XML (ou JSON) na comunicação de páginas com os usuários.