# Como fazer requisições com Guzzle\Http fingindo ser "AJAX"?

Tags: php, guzzle

Costumo utilizar a biblioteca`Guzzle\Http` para poder fazer requisições à algumas urls com PHP.

Estou fazendo webservice com sistemas nossos, onde, se a requisição for reconhecida como `Ajax`, o resultado retornado é `Json`. Caso contrário, é retornado `HTML`.

Porém, preciso agora fazer requisições nessas urls com o `Guzzle`, e quero que, quando a requisição for feita pelo `Guzzle`, também me seja retornado a resposta em `Json`.

Como fazer requisições com a biblioteca `Guzzle\Http`, como se ele fosse o AJAX executado por um navegador?

Preciso colocar algum ou alguns headers para isso funcionar?

Comment: A pessoa que deu o negativo podia oferecer informações no que poderia ser melhorado na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade não tem como detectar se é ajax de verdade (e isso é o que nos ajuda), o que fazemos é um envio de um *header* que usa o prefixo `x-`, geralmente em HTTP o uso desse prefixo quer dizer experimental.

Um caso de uso disto é o jQuery, por exemplo eu criar uma simples requisição GET com `XmlHttpRequest` sem nada eu não vou ter como detectar, então o jQuery envia esse header:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Não quer dizer que é Ajax, na verdade quer dizer que é `XMLHttpRequest` (como explicado aqui [Ajax não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/3635))

No caso detectamos se o envio é `XMLHttpRequest`, no `Guzzle\Http` você pode definir na instância do `Guzzle\Http`, para "herdar" as configurações em outras requisições. Assim, você simplifica a configuração:

```
  $client = new Guzzle\Http(['headers' => ['X-Request-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']]);

  $client->put(/** **/);

  $client->post(/** **/);

  $client->get(/** **/);
```

Ou usando o `GuzzleHttp\Client` assim:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(...);

$client->request('GET', '/caminho/foo/bar/baz', [
    'headers' => ['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']
]);
```

Apenas um adicional, frameworks como Laravel e cakephp usam estes métodos pra detectar se é possui o header `X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest`:

- Laravel:

  ```
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
      if($request->ajax()){
  ```
- cakephp:

  ```
  if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
  ```

Comment: O `Symfony` então, de acordo com sua opnião, fez certo. Lá o método chamasse `$request->isXMLHttpRequest()`. Creio que o `$request->isAjax()` veio para "simplificar a bicicleta".

Comment: @WallaceMaxters no meu framework é apenas `Request::is('xhr')` :)