# Botão no javascript executar ação no php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, variáveis, conexão

Olá.
Tenho uma dúvida :/

Estou fazendo um site de animes, com postagem e etc, no começo pensei que conseguiria fazer tudo em javascript, porém, agora tive que usar php para acessar a Database e etc.

**Problema**
Tenho um botão que quando é clicado deve executar uma ação no php (Alterar valor na Database).

Obs. Comecei a usar PHP à 3 dias, sejam pacientes comigo.

Obrigado =D

Comment: Já tens algum código no JavaScript? Sabes o que é ajax?

Comment: Não, já ouvi falar de AJAX, mas não sei programar. Mas se necessitar obrigatoriamente, posso aprender.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/129

Comment: Hááááá, já usei AJAX sem saber. Devo usar ajax para abrir páginas php dentro da página inicial e executar o que preciso?

Comment: Tens de usar ajax para enviar e receber dados do servidor. Sabes como ativar o ajax (e passar eventuais valores) quando o botão fôr clicado?

Comment: Eu ativo ajax com url meusite.com/acao.php?teste=teste2 e coloco o código a ser executado dendo do acao.php usando: $_REQUEST correto?