# Qual a diferença entre o SSE e Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, sse

Estou querendo atualizar uma `div` que contém os créditos de um cliente, assim que atualizar no Banco a quantidade de créditos dele e estou usando o `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){
    ver_creditos();
}, 60000);
```

Então vi a função do `HTML5`, o `EventSource (SSE)` e fiz um teste, e pelo console vi que ele faz requisições de 5 em 5 segundos.

Nessa minha questão, queria saber qual dessas suas funções seria melhor para a minha utilidade, e qual delas usaria menos o servidor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O Ajax é uma requisição HTTP normal, mas que roda em `background`, o Ajax é para ser mais exato é uma *"maneira"* de se usar a API `XmlHttpRequest` de modo assíncrono, mas de qualquer forma a requisição é uma requisição normal HTTP, ele requisita uma vez recebe a resposta e fecha o pedido, mais detalhes em:

- [Ajax não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/3635)

[O **server-sent events** (SSE) é diferente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), ele é mais **semelhante** ao [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets), todavia *diferente do WebSocket*, o SSE pode funcionar em um servidor HTTP normal, como deve saber o PHP, asp.net-mvc e outros tecnologias web rodam no *lado do servidor* e só lhe enviam a resposta quando você solicita/requisita, então quando você faz isto:

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("api.php");
```

Você estará em **uma especie de conexão persistente**, ou seja o `api.php` pode ficar em um loop infinito, sem nunca terminar, ao invés de *você pegar* a resposta é como se o PHP lhe enviasse a resposta a hora que ele deseja-se, por exemplo:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");

$counter = rand(1, 10);

while (1) {  
  echo "event: ping\n";
  $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
  echo 'data: ' . $curDate;
  echo "\n\n";
        
  $counter--;
  
  if (!$counter) {
    echo 'data: This is a message at time ' . $curDate . "\n\n";
    $counter = rand(1, 10);
  }
  
  ob_end_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

A cada segundo é o *PHP "quem vai enviar uma requisição"* (relativamente falando) para o client-side, e você vai ficar observando com:

```
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(e.data); //Pega a resposta do PHP
}
```

### Formato SSE

O sse tem um formato um pouco padrão, primeiro é necessário passar o `Content-Type: text/event-stream` nos headers, e então o que seria equivalente ao body deve conter estes campos (não todos ao mesmo tempo, depende muito do que deseja fazer):

- **event**:

  Se especificado um evento será disparado na janela/aba que foi iniciado o SSE, o evento irá chamar um evento adicionado com `addEventListener` ao próprio `new EventSource`, caso não tenha um evento nomeado será disparado o `onmessage`
- **data**

  Envia uma "string" para o `onmessage`, se necessitar de multiplas linhas será necessário que todas comecem com `data:`, o `EventSource` receberá todas linhas concactenadas, quebras de linha serão removidas
- **id**

  É usado para identificar o evento, claro que pode alterar, creio ser mais para uso de saber quem esta chamando o que.
- **retry**

  Define o tempo para se reconectar ao tentar enviar um evento, se o script no lado servidor não estiver em loop o `EventSource` finaliza sozinho e tenta novamente após o último tempo definido em `retry` (se definido), caso contrário creio que usa o tempo padrão, aparentemente ele também tenta conectar novamente se tiver problemas com conexão.

### Suporte

Conforme o [**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/#search=eventsource) os navegadores que suportam o SSE são:

- Chorme 6
- Firefox 6
- Safari 5
- Browser nativo do Android 4.4

> Nota: Internet Explorer e Microsoft Edge não suportam SSE, o Edge esta em construção, talvez logo tenha suporte

Alguns BUGs ou detalhes sobre suporte relatados:

- CORS em `EventSource` só é suportado a partir do Firefox 10+, Opera 12+, Chrome 26+ e  Safari 7.0+.
- Até a versão 36 do Firefox havia um bug, acaso houve-se perda de conexão o próprio `EventSource` não tentava reconectar, apesar do que foi dito pelo **caniuse** é possivel você contornar isto usado a propriedade `evtSource.readystate` para checar qual o estado:

  - Retorna `0` se estiver conectando ainda
  - Retorna `1` se estiver aberto
  - Retorna `2` se estiver fechado, ou seja, você pode adicionar um `setTimeout` para ficar checando e se for `2` você mesmo pode tentar reabrir.
- Até Firefox 52 não havia suporte para `EventSource` em *web/shared workers*
- Eventualmente programas de Antivirus software talvez possam bloquear ou causar algum conflito (não sei bem como ocorre, se achar algo sobre isto irei editar a resposta).

### Testando o SSE

A [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/) deixou um exemplo em PHP: https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/tree/master/server-sent-events, todavia criei um exemplo mais simples, se estiver usando PHP, crie um script chamando `chatbox.html` (não precisa ser `.php`, mas não faz diferença neste caso) com este conteudo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<button id="close">Terminar conversa</button>
<div id="chatbox"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var btnClose = document.getElementById("close");
var chatbox = document.getElementById("chatbox");
var evtSource = new EventSource("chat.php");

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    var n = document.createElement("p");

    n.innerHTML = "message: " + e.data;
    chatbox.appendChild(n);
};

btnClose.onclick = function () {
    evtSource.close(); //Finaliza a conexão do SSE
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

E então no crie na mesma pasta um arquivo com o nome `chat.php` e adicione este conteúdo:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');

$canned = array(
    'Oi?',
    'Quer tc?',
    'você é de onde?',
    'Poderia me ajudar com uma duvida de JS?',
    'já usou o stack overflow?',
    'Vamos jogar um fut?'
);

$size = count($canned) - 1;

echo 'data: <strong>Você entrou na sala!</strong>';

echo "\n\n"; //Requer duas quebras de linha


//Loop "infinito"
while (1) {

    //Pega uma "mensagem pronta" aleatória
    $response = $canned[mt_rand(0, $size)];

    echo 'data: ', htmlentities($response);

    echo "\n\n"; //Requer duas quebras de linha

    flush();

    //Varia entre 1 e 4 segundos para que o PHP envia uma nova mensagem para o SSE
    sleep(mt_rand(1, 4));
}
```

Este script simula uma pessoa mandando mensagens para você, é apenas para entender o comportamento

Comment: *Vamos jogar um fut?* só se for agora xD!

Comment: SSE é mais leve que Ajax para o servidor então?

Comment: O script PHP que fica rodando no servidor, ele é destruído automaticamente assim que a conexão é finalizada? Precisaria usar o `connection_aborted ()` ?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Essa coisa de "leve" é muito relativa, quero dizer, o script PHP vai ficar aberto constantemente, então ele não vai precisar ficar sendo reinterpretado (php não é compilado), isto ajuda sim o servidor, mas é algo que pode ser bem relativo, depende muito do que você fez no back-end, por isto não citei questão de melhor ou pior.

Comment: @Everson irei verificar e lhe aviso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu imaginei que com SSE gera-se menos tráfego e menos overhead devido a cargas do http. Não estava falando de nenhum backend em particular. De modo geral, pela sua resposta, parece que evita mesmo um bom peso de uma chamada Ajax

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim basicamente é isto que ocorre com conexões persistentes geralmente, diminuir requisições HTTP ajuda muito, principalmente se for algo bem pesado do lado do back-end, mas se for uma coisa leve, talvez nem sinta muita melhora, quero dizer provavelmente haverá, mas será tão minima que você nem vai sentir, eu vou tentar confirmar os detalhes, se a conexão persistente puder ser compartilhada com todas abas ou o mesmo script que estiver rodando enviar resposta para todos SSE então creio que terá um ganho significativo. Talvez eu formule algo sobre Websocket, ajax e SSE

Answer (score 2):

Um ponto importante a considerar é que o IE não suporta SSE, você deve utilizar um [polyfill como esse](https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js) se quiser ou uma biblioteca como a [Yaffle](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource)

Server Sent Events geram menos tráfico no servidor pois cliente não precisa ficar solicitando dados ao servidor para descobrir que nada mudou, a informação é enviada somente quando estiver disponível.