# Requisições multiplas com $.ajax, de forma sincrona

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo um sistema, e nele preciso enviar diversos dados para o servidor, basicamente sincronizar um array de objetos em um servidor via json usando javascript, até ai não há problema, porem a requisição é $.ajax, que é assincrona, e por isto, não tenho como controlar os dados depois, nem salvar os dados ao fim da execução de todas as requisições.

Tenho feito com um for, e encontrei na net, primeiro que poderia usar async:true, porem, vi tambem que esta função foi depreciada, logo, deve-se usar promise ou callback, porem ambos não consegui implementar, há algum exemplo de como posso fazer isto?

## Editado para esclarecer o problema

Minuciando o problema, consiste em uma repetição de chamadas ajax para um servidor onde cada objeto no array é um objeto cadastrado no serviço, porem, ao final de todas as chamadas, eu salvo no localstorage todo o array, este array tem certa consistencia, já que é um array de dados que podem ou não já estár no banco, logo, uso a id(que o banco provem) para averiguar se o objeto está cadastrado, se existe id no objeto, logo está no serviço.

Mas voltando ao principal, o que ocorre é que ao enviar um dado ao servidor, a chamada assincrona do $.ajax, se colocar para que em cada sucesso o dado seja salvo, isto resulta em que em alguns casos, o resultado final acaba sendo informações com e sem a id. resultando em um comportamento imprevisto. isto pq, as chamadas ajax, elas por serem assincronas, não terminam em serie, e em paralelo sendo que cada uma a seu tempo.

#### Não é só informação, caso alguem tenha uma tecnica que resolva o problema, garanto que varios desenvolvedores ficarão gratos, claro, eu muito mais.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do(s) ajax(s)  que precisas enviar?

Comment: São basicamente posts, posts para um servidor, mas o retorno atualiza um array que está em uma localstorage.

Comment: Sua pergunta está MUITO confusa. Você precisa dividir ela em parte menores. Não dá pra entender muito do que você quer. Postar o código ajudaria muito, inclusive.

Answer (score 4):

Ajax síncrono (Sjax) está [sendo descontinuado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116177/3635) pelos navegadores (não pelo jQuery, isso é "consequência") e provavelmente será removido, o que precisa é aprender a usar callback, Promise é opcional.

Em JavaScript quase sempre usamos callback, até o click em um elemento que dispara um evento é um callback.

> $.ajax, que é assíncrona, e por isto, não tenho como controlar os dados depois, nem salvar os dados ao fim da execução de todas as requisições.

Não, você esta entendendo errado, a requisição não ocorre "junto", ela ocorre em paralero, mas só é entregue depois que o `readyState` for igual a `4`, quando chegar no 4 a requisição já vai ter terminado, creio que talvez você não tenha entendido a diferença de back-end e front-end, são camadas diferentes, locais diferentes.

> não tenho como controlar os dados depois

Não entendi o "controlar", talvez você queira popular um elemento HTML, por exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pagina.php" //Sua página
}).done(function( data ) {
    $("query para o elemento html").html(data);
}).fail(function (erro) {
    console.log("Houve um erro na requisição", erro);
});
```

Se for retornar um Json o jQuery é inteligente (geralmente tem que ter o `Content-Type` definido) e detecta então supondo que retorne algo como:

```
[
    {"foo": "valor 1"}, { "bar": "valor 2" }
]
```

o Ajax deve ficar assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pagina.php" //Sua página
}).done(function( data ) {
    var target = $("query para o elemento html");
    target.html(""); //Apaga o conteudo do "inner" atual

    for (var k in data) {
        //Adiciona os elementos
        $("<p></p>").html(k + ": " + data[v]);
    }
}).fail(function (erro) {
    console.log("Houve um erro na requisição", erro);
});
```

Documentação: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ainda não é isto que é meu problema, salvo a informação, retornada do servidor, que atualiza o array em um localstorage, e a informação tem sido comprometida no processo de salvar, pq por ser em paralelo tem dado diversos erros, como criação multiplas de dados no backend, pois o localstorage não está atualizado com todas as informações de cadastro.

Comment: @AndersoneyRodrigues isto você **não** informou na pergunta, então edite e forneça algo que possamos entender, faça como é recomendado no Help do site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve