# Como capturar 'responseText' de object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como faço para capturar o `responseText`?

```
var result = $.ajax({
    type : "POST", 
    data: "idTecnico=" + 1, 
    url : './Procedimentos/Servicos/ObterNomeTecnico.php'});
console.log(result);
var nomeTecnico = result;
```

Gostaria que a variável `nomeTecnico` recebece o resultado em string

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionado: [Ajax não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Requisições multiplas com $.ajax, de forma sincrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218526/3774)

Answer (score 2):

Consegui da seguinte forma:

```
// NOME DO TECNICO
$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   data: "idTecnico=" + dado.idTecnico,         
   url : './Procedimentos/Utilitarios/ObterNomeTecnico.php',
}).then(function(data){         
    var nomeTecnico = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#tecnicoView').val(nomeTecnico);
});
```