# Como realizar post sem recarregar a pagina?

Tags: php, javascript

Como faço para realizar um post para outra pagina sem precisar ir para ele, quero enviar os dados e aparecer o retorno na mesma pagina se deu certo ou não o envio, mas não sei como fazer. Já vi algo assim com JavaScript:

```
$.post
```

Mais ai não lembro o seguimento e não achei algo que entende-se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto `$.post` **não** é uma função JavaScript, é uma função que faz parte de uma lib/biblioteca para JavaScript que é adicionada manualmente por ti.

Essa biblioteca/lib pode ser que seja [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com) ou pode ser que seja [`Zepto`](http://zeptojs.com) (ou outra compatível)<s>, nenhum dos exemplos nas demais respostas vai funcionar só de adicionar em sua página, pois depende de adicionar o jQuery/Zepto nela primeiro.</s>

- Documentação jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
- Documentação Zepto: http://zeptojs.com/#$.post

---

### Usando com jQuery/Zepto

Se for usar jQuery primeiro adicione isto dentro de `<head>` (ou no final da página, antes do `<body>`):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Se for Zepto adicione isto:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js"></script>
```

Então após essa tag você pode adicionar uma outra tag como isto:

```
  <script src="meujs.js"></script>
```

E deve criar na mesma pasta um `meujs.js` com o seguinte conteúdo (não precisa ser exatamente assim):

```
$(function () { //<--- o $(...) equivale a função $.ready(...) que só executa um script quando o DOM (document) tiver sido carregado
      $.post("pagina_que_ira_receber_o_post.php", {
          "variavel1": "valor A",
          "variavel2": "valor B",
          "variavel3": "valor C"
      }).done(function (data) {
          alert(data); //Pega a resposta da pagina_que_ira_receber_o_post.php
      }).fail(function (error) {
          alert(error); //Pega o erro, podendo ser uma exception no parse ou um erro HTTP
      });
});
```

A página deve ficar assim:

```
...
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="meujs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
```

---

### JavaScript puro

Você **não** precisar uma lib (biblioteca) inteira para usar o Ajax (semelhante aos $.ajax, $.post, $.get), pode simplesmente usar a API nativa do navegador chamada `XmlHttpRequest`.

Aproveite e dê uma lida nisto:

- [Ajax não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/3635)

Exemplo de envio de POST:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Defina como true
oReq.open("POST", "pagina_que_ira_receber_o_post.php", true);

//Função assíncrona que aguarda a resposta
oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
        if (oReq.status >= 200 && oReq.status <= 299) {
            alert(oReq.responseText);// Pega a resposta da pagina_que_ira_receber_o_post.php
        } else {
            alert("Erro HTTP na requisição: " + oReq.status);
        }
    }
};

var variaveis = {
    "variavel1": "valor A",
    "variavel2": "valor B",
    "variavel3": "valor C"
};

var campos = {};

for (var k in variaveis) {
    campos[escape(k)] = escape(variaveis[k]);
}

//Envia a requisição, mas a resposta fica sendo aguardada em Background
oReq.send(campos);
```

Comment: Já que você não fez propaganda deixa eu fazer por você : "Você também pode usar a Lib [Pjax](https://github.com/brcontainer/pjax.js) e deixar sua pagina dinâmica sem necessidade de ficar recarregando tudo de novo"

Comment: É uma ótima lib exponha ela :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert kkkkk, é que tá quase saindo a versão 0.6.0, que pretendo que seja "mais prática" :) - vou postar naquela pergunta sobre Pjax mesmo, mas obrigado por lembrar, eu preciso ser menos humilde e começar a fazer mais jabas hehehe

Answer (score 0):

De forma complementar à resposta do [Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260983/5878), podemos também fazer a requisição com JavaScript puro através da API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). No momento, ela ainda é uma ferramenta experimental, porém já possui suporte nos principais navegadores e possui um [*polyfill*](https://github.com/github/fetch) caso precise de suporte em outros navegadores.

Com o `fetch`, uma requisição POST que envia os dados de um formúlario, por exemplo, ficaria semelhante à:

```js
const data = new FormData( document.getElementById('form') );
const request = fetch('pagina.php', {method: 'POST', body: data});

request.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        // A requisição foi feita com sucesso...
    } else {
        // Algo de errado não está certo...
    }
});

request.catch(error => {
    // Parece que tem algo errado no `fetch`...
});
```

A função `fetch` basicamente retorna uma [promessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/5878) e, se você entender o que é uma promessa, o código fica bem fácil de entender. O primeiro parâmetro da função é uma URI que identifica o recurso no servidor, enquanto o segundo parâmetro é um objeto que configura a requisição, neste caso, definindo o método da requisição e os dados enviados pelo corpo da mesma.

Se você gosta de semântica, é possível deixar o código mais semântico. Na própria API do `fetch` são definidas algumas classes que auxiliam nesta parte, a citar: `Request`, `Headers` e `Response`. Desta forma, você pode definir os cabeçalhos da sua requisição através de `Headers`:

```
const headers = new Headers({'Origin': '...'});
headers.append('X-Custom-Header', '...');
```

E a requisição através da classe `Request`:

```
const request = new Request('pagina.php', {method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: data});
```

Passando o objeto `request` para a função `fetch`:

```
fetch(request).then(response => { ... });
```

Assim, ao ser realizada a requisição, o parâmetro `response` passado à função *callback* será uma instância da classe `Response`.

Leia mais na [especificação do `fetch` na WHATWG](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/).