# Carregando script assincronamente

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Tenho um sistema administrativo usando adminLTE. No menu lateral carrego todos os meus scripts assincronamente (ao menos era o esperado). Porem quando carrego um HTML de forma assíncrona, e dentro desse arquivo coloco carregar um javascript externo, ele me gera o seguinte aviso:

> jquery.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Segue o código que estou usando para carregar os arquivos

```
$.ajax(url+"teste").done(function(data) {
    $("#ajax-content").html(data);
    $('#loadingMenu').remove(); // Retira o gif de loading
});
```

O arquivo que eu carrego é esse:

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>HTML carregado assincronamente</h1>
</div>
<script src="meuScript.js"></script>
```

Se coloco o código javascript direto no arquivo HTML não gera nenhum erro.

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>HTML carregado assincronamente</h1>
</div>
<script>
   alert('agora não gera aviso');
</script>
```

Como faço pra carregar esse script sem a necessidade de colocar ele na mesma página HTML?

Comment: Você está confundindo síncrono com assíncrono!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mensagem diz o contrário do que você entendeu;

O que esta sendo descontinuado (se tornou obsoleto) é o **SÍNCRONO** (que trava o navegador muitas vezes), por exemplo isto é **síncrono**:

```
xhr.open("GET", "/foo/bar", false);
```

E isto é ASSÍNCRONO:

```
xhr.open("GET", "/foo/bar", true);
```

Nesta resposta eu explico o que é Ajax e Sjax:

- [**Ajax não é uma linguagem de programação. Então o que é?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116177/3635)

Claro que o código acima é JS puro, mas o jQuery internamente usa JavaScript.

**No entanto** como o @ValdeirPsr disse, é um problema na função `jQuery.parseHTML` (e/ou dependencias), usada internamente na função `$(seletor).load("...");`

Ou seja é um bug no jQuery, e é provavel que logo eles corrijam.

Comment: Sim, fui olhar melhor e percebi que confundi síncrono e assíncrono. Estou usando uma versão mais nova no adminLTE. Troquei meu código que carrega a página e agora estou usando $.ajax("teste").done(function(data) {
   alert();
  });
Mesmo usando a função ajax está dando a msg

Comment: editei a pergunta acrescentando mais informações. Se puder dar uma olhada

Comment: Editei mais uma vez. Se não ficar claro o suficiente vou tentar reformular uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Eu coloquei exatamente o código que gera o problema. adminLTE não tem nada a ver com o problema. Só falei dele para dar uma noção de como estou trabalhando o carregamento do conteúdo. O código é exatamente esse. Tenho um script que quando eu clico em um botão ele roda essa função ajax, trazendo o html como retorno.

Comment: @Phelipe se você "debugar" o código, verá que a resposta está correta. O `jQuery` faz essa requisição de forma síncrona. Na versão `3.2.1` você poderá debugar na linha `9497`. O valor do propriedade `options.async`, será falsa.

Comment: E mesmo que você utilize `$.ajax({url: "index3.html", async:true})`, o `meuScript.js` será carregado de forma síncrona, por padrão. Por isso utilize `<script>$.getScript('meuScript.js');</script>` na outra página HTML para carrega-lo de forma assíncrona.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não funciona. Eu testei com `async` e `defer`. O `jQuery` ignora esses atributos.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72935/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-valdeir-psr).

Comment: @Phelipe editei a resposta, é um BUG do jQuery mesmo, o jeito é esperar eles resolverem, mas por enquanto seus script irão funcionar, a mensagem é somente um aviso.