# Requisição Ajax voltando undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-service

Estou estudando um pouco de Ajax e testando suas requisições. A minha dúvida fica por conta do retorno, ele está voltando undefined.

Essa é a função:

```
function recarregar()
{
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "http://xxxxxxx/o/Ano/1235",
        dataType: "text",
        method: "Post"
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    var teste = jsonData;
}


setInterval(recarregar(), 10000);
```

Essa é o retorno segundo o Postman

[image: Uma imagem de um console mostrando o valor 152806]

Comment: Você não precisa usar `async:false`, use o done ou fail como mostra na documentação : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

> **Nota:**
>   Esta faltando uma virgula entre post" e `async`:
>
> ```
>     method: "Post"
>     async: false
> ```

Por favor **NÃO use `async: false`**, isto esta obsoleto e no futuro os navegadores irão remover esta funcionalidade, isto porque o modo sincronizado costuma congelar o navegador, diferente do assíncrono, como expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116177/3635

E como é descrito em https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning

Então mude a abordagem para usar *callbacks*, para entender o que é callback leia esta resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635

Então troque o setInterval por setTimeout, assim irá só chamar o proximo se o primeiro tiver sido enviado

```
function recarregar()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://xxxxxxx/o/Ano/1235",
        dataType: "text",
        method: "POST"
    }).done(function (jsonData) {
         var teste = jsonData;
    }).always(function () {
         setTimeout(recarregar, 10000);
    });
}
```

Agora sobre o motivo de estar retornando `undefined` deve ser devido **ao escopo** das variaveis, para passar o acesso da variavel teste você teria que ou colocar ela como global (no escopo de `window.`) e ainda adicionar algum tipo de *refresh* no DOM especifico que deseja alterar com o valor, ou então mudar a abordagem totalmente.

Se aprender a usar bem os callback provavelmente vai conseguir ajustar tudo, se puder indicar aonde deseja colocar o valor de `teste` posso ajustar o código e te dar alguma sugestão.

Comment: estou atualizando somente um numero, ele está no front como uma Label. então essa minha função iria atualizar essa Label a cada x minutos

Comment: @Antonio_Sistema_de_Informacao não tem haver com atualizar, nem com GET ou POST, o problema é como a API XmlHttpRequest funciona e que no futuro não vai mais suportar `async:false`, pois isto é o mesmo que assincrono que já é algo obsoleto a muito tempo e os navegadores irão no futuro remover, fazendo só callback funcionar para Ajax, ou seja seu código no futuro irá falhar se continuar em insistir em usar o modo sincronizado ao invés do assincronizado. Leia com a calma a resposta e estude os links que lhe indiquei.

Comment: Muito obrigado, estou vendo os link compartilhados e estou entendendo o erro da aplicação.