# Django. Somente alterar no banco via html

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Estou desenvolvendo em Django faz pouco tempo, tenho uma imagem curtir no meu site, quando clico nela gostaria de somente alterar um campo no banco sem recarregar ou reenviar a página e ficar no mesmo local.

Eu tenho como chamar uma função do Python direto no html ou via javascript qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Pesquisei em vários locais e não encontrei um resposta, a unica forma que achei foi passando via url, mas ai teria que renderizar a pagina novamente?

Estou utilizando django 2.1 e python 3.7
Desde já agradeço o auxilio.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow. Creio que a resposta seja Ajax. Dê uma lida sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116153/ajax-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ent%C3%A3o-o-que-%C3%A9

Comment: Obrigada Wallace, sou realmente nova nesse mundo javascript e html, já havia ouvido falar de Ajax, mas nunca parei para olhar, vou estudar, obrigada pelo link. Abraços

Comment: Recentemente utilizei o [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) e particularmente ele funcionou bem com Django/Flask em um primeiro teste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você quer enviar algo pro backend (seu sistema) sem ter que recarregar a página, então você vai precisar usar uma chamada AJAX usando javascript. [Nesse post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) e [nesse](https://www.devmedia.com.br/ajax-com-jquery-trabalhando-com-requisicoes-assincronas/37141) você vai ver uma maneira de fazer isso. Mas seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
  <script>
    $("#image").onclick(function () {

      $.ajax({
        url: '/url/da/view/que/vai/processar/essa/chamada/',
        data: {
          'id': algumacoisa.id,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("A user with this username already exists.");
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Obrigado Mazulo, fui estudar um pouco de Jquery e Ajax e consegui montar com este teu exemplo... Abraços