# Objetivo do Jquery em php

Tags: php

Em minha graduação, estudei sobre RIA - internet rica e não fixei muito bem o conceito da utilização da biblioteca jquery(JS) em linguagens web. Alguém poderia me esclarecer? Obrigado!

Comment: PHP é uma linguagem _backend_, ou seja, roda no servidor e tem por objetivo "montar" a página HTML e enviar para o cliente (geralmente o seu navegador). Enquanto o jQuery é uma biblioteca em JS que roda no cliente. São assuntos completamente paralelos, pois os dois não têm relação nenhuma, o jQuery não sabe (e não precisa saber) quem foi que montou o HTML ou se o HTML é estático.

Comment: Bem, pesquisando agora o argumento era similar, com algumas diferenças no qual a Js  usando a biblioteca Jquery fazia requisições em tempo de execução(real) para que a aplicação web ficasse similar a uma desktop não precisando recarregar a página php toda hora..

Comment: Aí você está falando de [AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116153/ajax-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ent%c3%a3o-o-que-%c3%a9) que, resumidamente, é uma forma de fazer uma requisição para um servidor de forma assíncrona usando JS sem precisar recarregar a página. Mas ainda sim, este servidor pode ser qualquer coisa, não necessariamente PHP.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Só para elucidar, o jQuery resolveu um problema em sua época e que hoje não é tão evidente, a incompatibilidade de código entre navegadores. É claro que jQuery ainda tem utilidade, mas as principais funcionalidades dele já são nativas em navegadores modernos e tem uma compatibilidade descente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `JQuery` não tem um objetivo especialmente para `PHP`, podendo ser trabalhado com outras linguagens da mesma forma.

É uma biblioteca `JavaScript` rica em recursos para desenvolvimento rápido de páginas e documentos `HTML` sendo possível manipular componentes, imagens, animações, requisições *AJAX* entre outros sendo uma `API` de fácil aprendizado e funcional em vários navegadores.

Exemplos `JQuery`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Vai sumir hein</p>
<button onclick='$("p").hide()'>Esconder</button>
```

No código acima facilmente você pode selecionar um componente e escondê-lo.

Outro exemplo é a atribuição de um evento à um elemento:

```js
$('#ID_Elemento').on('click', function (){ 
  alert('Evento onClick() funcionando!')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ID_Elemento">Clique</button>
```

Você pode obter mais exemplos e informações no site do próprio [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)