# Validação de dados no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Eu criei alguns campos na minha pagina e estou tentando fazer a validação desses dados usando js, porem por algum motivo ele não está funcionando, fiz apenas um teste no primeiro campo.

Segue o meu código no html e js, o `name=contrato` está sendo usado para retornar os dados que foram inseridos nos campos do formulário, o `id=estilo` esta sendo usado para formatar o formulário no css, mas esses dados acredito eu n fazem diferença nesse erro. Agora o `onsubmit="return validar(this)"` está sendo usado para chamar a função que foi criado no meu javascript.

```js
function validar(formDados) {
    if (formDados.primeiro.value == "") {
        alert("Digite um valor para o campo \"Nome\".");
        formDados.primeiro.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function enviar() {

    var primeiro = document.contrato.primeiro.value;
    var segundo = document.contrato.segundo.value;
    var terceiro = document.contrato.terceiro.value;
    var quarto = document.contrato.quarto.value;
    var quinto = document.contrato.quinto.value;
    var sexto = document.contrato.sexto.value;
    var text_area = document.contrato.comentario.value;
    var valor = document.contrato.oitavo.value;

    //retornando o dia e o ano atual
    var dNow = new Date();
    var localdate = "Jundiai, " + dNow.getDate() + " de maio de " + dNow.getFullYear();

    //trocando o ponto pela virgula
    var troca = parseFloat(valor.replace(".", ","));

    //calculando o valor do acrescimo de 10%
    valor = (10 / 100 * troca + troca);

    //usando um 'modo' que o valor retornado fique no formato BR
    pt_br = Number(valor).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: "currency", currency: "BRL" });


    //chamando a tag 'estilo' do css
    var form = document.getElementById("estilo");

    //escondendo o formulario, pois ele apareceria 2x
    form.style.visibility = "hidden";

    //pegando id do body da pagina para manipula-lo
    var corpo = document.getElementById('body');

    //criando uma nova div no body para armazenar os dados retornados
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    //atribuindo um novo id=estilo para a div, assim deixando-a formatada
    div.setAttribute('id', 'estilo')

    //adicionando os dados retornados na pagina
    div.innerHTML =
        `${localdate} </br></br>
         CONTRATANTE (Tomador(a) de Serviços): Sr(a) ${primeiro} </br></br>
         Brasileiro(a), residente e domiciliado(a) na Rua: ${segundo} </br></br>
         N° ${terceiro} </br></br>
         Cidade de: ${quarto} </br></br>
         Estado: ${quinto} </br></br>
         CPF ou CNPJ: ${sexto} </br></br>
         Referente a Prestação de Serviços do tipo: ${text_area} </br></br>
         Valor: R$ ${pt_br}`

    //adicionando a div criada ao body da pagina
    body.appendChild(div);

    return true
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="teste03.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>
        

</head>





<body id="body">

    <form name="contrato" id="estilo"  onsubmit="return validar(this)">


        <div>


            <div id="h1">
                Contrato de Serviços
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                CONTRATANTE (Tomador(a) de Serviços): Sr(a).
                <input type="text" name="primeiro">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                Brasileiro(a), residente e domiciliado(a) na Rua
                <input type="text" name="segundo">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                N° <input type="number" name="terceiro">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                Cidade de: <input type="text" id="quarto">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                Estado: <input type="text" name="quinto"> <br>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                CPF ou CNPJ: <input type="text" name="sexto">
            </div>


            <br>


            <div class="p">

                <p>Referente a Prestação de Serviços do tipo: <br>
                    <textarea name="comentario" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

            </div>

            <div class="p">
                Valor: <input type="number" name="oitavo">
            </div>

            <br>

            <input type="button" name="" id="bt" value="enviar" onclick="enviar();">

        </div>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ola @Giovanni, Bem vindo ao SOpt, não esqueça de fazer nosso [Tour] para entender como a comunidade funciona =D

Comment: Fundamental nestes casos reduzir o problema a um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) antes de postar.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo teste que eu fiz está tudo funcionando. O único detalhe é que seu botão para envio de formulário não é do tipo `submit`. Esse botão também chama uma função chamada `enviar`, caso essa função esteja fazendo o `submit` via JavaScript, então de fato da maneira que você fez não irá funcionar, pois o evento `onsubmit` disparado pelo JS não é capturado. Se for esse o caso, chame a função de validação dentro da função enviar.

```js
function validar(formDados) {
    if (formDados.primeiro.value == "") {
        alert("Digite um valor para o campo \"Nome\".");
        formDados.primeiro.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="contrato" id="estilo" onsubmit="return validar(this)">
  <div>
    <div id="h1">
      Contrato de Serviços
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="p">
      CONTRATANTE (Tomador(a) de Serviços): Sr(a).
      <input type="text" name="primeiro">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="p">
      Brasileiro(a), residente e domiciliado(a) na Rua
      <input type="text" name="segundo">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="p">
      N° <input type="number" name="terceiro">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="p">
      Cidade de: <input type="text" id="quarto">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="p">
      Estado: <input type="text" name="quinto"> <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="p">
      CPF ou CNPJ: <input type="text" name="sexto">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="p">
      <p>Referente a Prestação de Serviços do tipo: <br>
        <textarea name="comentario" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>
    </div>
    <div class="p">
      Valor: <input type="number" name="oitavo">
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="" id="bt" value="enviar">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

O código esta funcionando, o problema e que seu botão esta como `button` e não `submit` <strike>e esta tentando chamar uma função `enviar()` que no código que você publicou não esta definida</strike>

#### Após atualização da pergunta

O seu `input[type='button']` foi alterado para `input[type='submit']` e o atributo `onclick="enviar();"` foi removido, deixando seu `input` como mostrado abaixo:

```html
<input type="submit" name="" id="bt" value="enviar">
```

Alterei a função que esta sendo chamada no `onsubmit` do form para `onsubmit="return enviar(this)"`.

Sua função `validar()` agora retorna `true` caso o formulário esteja **válido** e `false` caso ele seja **inválido**.

Sua função `enviar()` agora recebe o formulário como parâmetro e a primeira coisa que ela faz é executar a função `validar()` e verificar o resultado retornado para saber se deve continuar a execução.

No final da função `enviar()` você estava retornando `true` isso vai fazer o formulário ser enviado, como você não definiu os atributos `method=""` e o `action=""` ele vai enviar para a **url atual** por **get**, ou seja, **a pagina será recarregada e sua url ficará +/-** assim: `http://minhapagina.com/?primeiro=abc&segundo=dfg....`. Agora olhando sua função `enviar()` me parece que esse não é seu objetivo, pois você esta adicionando elementos na tela, então eu troquei seu `return true` no final da função por `return false` para o formulário não ser enviado.

<sup>Como nesse dentro da sua função `enviar()` você tem acesso aos dados do formulário, você pode utilizar uma outra forma de envio se assim desejar, como por exemplo enviar os dados por [`ajax`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/3774).</sup>

> Como as coisas estão executando agora?
>   Quando o usuário clicar no **botão enviar** o evento `onsubmit` será disparado, isso porque o botão agora e do tipo `input[type='submit']`:
>
> 1. O evento `onsubmit` irá chamar a função `enviar()`;
> 2. A função `enviar()` vai checar se o formulário foi bem preenchido (*esta válido*) para isso ela vai utilizar a sua função `validar()`
>
>    - Se **não** (*não foi bem preenchido*): para a execução retornando `false` para o evento `onsubmit` e o formulário não será enviado.
>    - Se **sim** (*foi bem preenchido*): continua a execução do seu script normalmente.
> 3. Se tudo ocorrer bem seu script vai adicionar elementos na tela e vai retornar `false` para o evento `onsubmit` para o formulário não ser enviado e a pagina não ser recarregada (*como expliquei acima*).

```js
function validar( formDados ) {
    if (formDados.primeiro.value == "") {
        alert("Digite um valor para o campo \"Nome\".");
        formDados.primeiro.focus();
        return false;
/// ;          ^ indica que a validação falhou
    }
    
    
    return true;
/// ;      ^ indica que o formulario foi validado
}

/// ; Mudei a função para ela receber o elemento form
function enviar( formDados ) {

    /// ; O primeiro passo aqui dentro será executar a 
    /// ; função validar, pegar o seu retorno e verificar
    /// ; se esta função pode continuar a executar
    
    if( !validar( formDados ) )
    {
        /// ; Validação falhou, para a execução.
        return false;
    }

    /// ; Continua com a execução do seu codigo;
    
    var primeiro = formDados.primeiro.value;
    var segundo = formDados.segundo.value;
    var terceiro = formDados.terceiro.value;
    var quarto = formDados.quarto.value;
    var quinto = formDados.quinto.value;
    var sexto = formDados.sexto.value;
    var text_area = formDados.comentario.value;
    var valor = formDados.oitavo.value;

    //retornando o dia e o ano atual
    var dNow = new Date();
    var localdate = "Jundiai, " + dNow.getDate() + " de maio de " + dNow.getFullYear();

    //trocando o ponto pela virgula
    var troca = parseFloat(valor.replace(".", ","));

    //calculando o valor do acrescimo de 10%
    valor = (10 / 100 * troca + troca);

    //usando um 'modo' que o valor retornado fique no formato BR
    pt_br = Number(valor).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: "currency", currency: "BRL" });


    //chamando a tag 'estilo' do css
    var form = document.getElementById("estilo");

    //escondendo o formulario, pois ele apareceria 2x
    form.style.visibility = "hidden";

    //pegando id do body da pagina para manipula-lo
    var corpo = document.getElementById('body');

    //criando uma nova div no body para armazenar os dados retornados
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    //atribuindo um novo id=estilo para a div, assim deixando-a formatada
    div.setAttribute('id', 'estilo')

    //adicionando os dados retornados na pagina
    div.innerHTML =
        `${localdate} </br></br>
         CONTRATANTE (Tomador(a) de Serviços): Sr(a) ${primeiro} </br></br>
         Brasileiro(a), residente e domiciliado(a) na Rua: ${segundo} </br></br>
         N° ${terceiro} </br></br>
         Cidade de: ${quarto} </br></br>
         Estado: ${quinto} </br></br>
         CPF ou CNPJ: ${sexto} </br></br>
         Referente a Prestação de Serviços do tipo: ${text_area} </br></br>
         Valor: R$ ${pt_br}`

    //adicionando a div criada ao body da pagina
    body.appendChild(div);

    return false;
    // return true;
    /// ; Se retornar true o formulario vai ser enviado
    /// ; e a pagina sera redirecionada.
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="teste03.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <form name="contrato" id="estilo"  onsubmit="return enviar(this)">
        <div>
            <div id="h1">
                Contrato de Serviços
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                CONTRATANTE (Tomador(a) de Serviços): Sr(a).
                <input type="text" name="primeiro">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                Brasileiro(a), residente e domiciliado(a) na Rua
                <input type="text" name="segundo">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                N° <input type="number" name="terceiro">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                Cidade de: <input type="text" id="quarto">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                Estado: <input type="text" name="quinto"> <br>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">
                CPF ou CNPJ: <input type="text" name="sexto">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="p">

                <p>Referente a Prestação de Serviços do tipo: <br>
                    <textarea name="comentario" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>

            </div>

            <div class="p">
                Valor: <input type="number" name="oitavo">
            </div>

            <br>

            <input type="submit" name="" id="bt" value="enviar">

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: eu troquei o button pelo submit e deu certo, a função enviar que esta sendo chamada é de outro arquivo js que esta recebendo essa função e retornando os dados, porem na hora de validar o nome, dps q eu clico em ok, mesmo eu nao tendo colocado o nome, ele parte para a tela de exibição, vc sabe como eu posso resolver isso ?

Comment: eu comentei o resto do código, se vc tiver duvida da uma olhada

Comment: @GiovanniManganotti, alterei a resposta, fiz outras alterações talvez te ajude. =D

Comment: obrigado cara, vc me ajudou muito, eu n gosto de ficar copiando as coisas dos outros, eu fiquei uns 20 minutos analisando para entender a logica e entendi, como sou novo em java script estou tendo um pouco de dificuldades, mas agradeço muito a atenção e a ajuda !!!!