# preventDefault() Não funciona junto com ajax/josn?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estou tendo esse problema que o preventDefault(), não funciona por nada dentro do ajax. Consigo ver perfeitamente no CONSOLE.LOG que ele que retorna false, já até testei com alert para garantir que ele faz o caminho do if e funciona.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/eng-verifica-email.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{"email_a" :email_a.val()},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("VERIFICA EMAIL: " + data)
        if (data == "false") {
            document.getElementById("msgerro").innerHTML="Este email já está sendo utilizado";
            form_reg.email_reg.focus()
            event.preventDefault()
        }else {

        }
    }
})
```

Eu estou usando outras estruturas de verificação que funcionam perfeitamente como:

```
if (nome == "") {
var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
div.innerHTML = "O nome deve ser preenchido!"
form_reg.pname_reg.focus()
event.preventDefault()
```

Ele realmente não deixa a tela atualizar, mas se eu completar todos os campos, mesmo com o email já existente no banco, por causa do ajax que não me deixa usar o preventDefault() ele enviar o form. Deis de já, agradeço.

```js
var form_cadastrar = document.querySelector('#form_reg');

form_cadastrar.onsubmit = function(event) {

  var nome = form_reg.pname_reg.value
  var email = form_reg.email_reg.value
  var cpf = form_reg.cpf_reg.value
  var rg = form_reg.rg_reg.value
  var senha = form_reg.pass_reg.value
  var confsenha = form_reg.confpass_reg.value
  var telefone = form_reg.tel_reg.value
  var endereco = form_reg.end_reg.value
  var estado = form_reg.esta_reg.value
  var emissor = form_reg.emi_reg.value
  var chave = form_reg.key_reg.value

  usuario = email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@"));
  dominio = email.substring(email.indexOf("@") + 1, email.length);

  if ((usuario.length >= 1) &&
    (dominio.length >= 3) &&
    (usuario.search("@") == -1) &&
    (dominio.search("@") == -1) &&
    (usuario.search(" ") == -1) &&
    (dominio.search(" ") == -1) &&
    (dominio.search(".") != -1) &&
    (dominio.indexOf(".") >= 1) &&
    (dominio.lastIndexOf(".") < dominio.length - 1)) {

    var email_a = $('#email')
    $.ajax({
      url: 'php/eng-verifica-email.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        "email_a": email_a.val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("VERIFICA EMAIL: " + data)
        if (data == "false") {
          document.getElementById("msgerro").innerHTML = "Este email já está sendo utilizado";
          form_reg.email_reg.focus()
          event.preventDefault()
        } else {

        }
      },
      error: function(responseText) {
        console.log(responseText)
      }
    })
  } else {
    document.getElementById("msgerro").innerHTML = "<Email não válido";
    form_reg.email_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  if (nome == "") {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "O nome deve ser preenchido!"
    form_reg.pname_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""

  }

  if (nome.length <= 7) {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "Digite seu nome corretamente!"
    form_reg.pname_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""

  }

  if (chave == 0) {
    if (cpf == "") {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "O CPF deve ser preenchido!"
      form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()
      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var cpf_a = $('#cpf_reg')
      $.ajax({
        url: 'php/eng-verifica-cpf.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          "cpf_a": cpf_a.val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("VERIFICA CPF: " + data)
          if (data == "false") {
            var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
            div.innerHTML = "Este CPF ja esta sendo utilizado!"
            form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()
            event.preventDefault()
          } else {

          }
        }
      })
    }

    if (cpf.length != 14 ||
      cpf == "000.000.000-00" ||
      cpf == "111.111.111-11" ||
      cpf == "222.222.222-22" ||
      cpf == "333.333.333-33" ||
      cpf == "444.444.444-44" ||
      cpf == "555.555.555-55" ||
      cpf == "666.666.666-66" ||
      cpf == "777.777.777-77" ||
      cpf == "888.888.888-88" ||
      cpf == "999.999.999-99") {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "CPF não valido!"
      form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()
      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = ""
    }

    cpf_temp = cpf.replace(".", "");
    cpf_temp = cpf_temp.replace(".", "");
    cpf_temp = cpf_temp.replace("-", "");

    var soma = 0
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) soma = soma + parseInt(cpf_temp.substring(i - 1, i)) * (11 - i);
    resto = (soma * 10) % 11;

    if ((resto == 10) || (resto == 11)) resto = 0;
    if (resto != parseInt(cpf_temp.substring(9, 10))) {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "CPF não valido!"
      form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()
      event.preventDefault()
    }

    var soma = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) soma = soma + parseInt(cpf_temp.substring(i - 1, i)) * (12 - i);
    resto = (soma * 10) % 11;

    if ((resto == 10) || (resto == 11)) resto = 0;
    if (resto != parseInt(cpf_temp.substring(10, 11))) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }



    if (rg == "") {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "O número de documento deve ser preenchido!"
      form_reg.rg_reg.focus()

      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var rg_a = $('#rg_reg')
      $.ajax({
        url: 'php/eng-verifica-rg.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          "rg_a": rg_a.val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("VERIFICA DOCUMENTO: " + data)
          if (data == "false") {
            var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
            div.innerHTML = "Este Documento já está sendo utilizado!"
            form_reg.rg_reg.focus()
            event.preventDefault()
          } else {

          }
        }
      })
    }

    if (emissor == "") {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "O emissor deve ser preenchido!"
      form_reg.emi_reg.focus()
      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = ""

    }
    if (emissor.length <= 1) {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "O emissor deve ser preenchido corretamente!"
      form_reg.emi_reg.focus()
      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = ""

    }
  }

  if (chave == 1) {
    if (cpf == "") {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "O CNPJ deve ser preenchido!"
      form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()

      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = ""

    }

    cpf_temp = cpf.replace(".", "")
    cpf_temp = cpf_temp.replace(".", "")
    cpf_temp = cpf_temp.replace("/", "")
    cpf_temp = cpf_temp.replace("-", "")

    if (cpf_temp.length !== 14) {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "CNPJ não valido!"
      form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()
      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = ""
    }

    d1 = cpf_temp.substr(12, 1)
    d2 = cpf_temp.substr(-1)

    cnpj_temp = cpf_temp.substr(0, 12)

    var array = cnpj_temp.split('')

    cnpj_0 = array[0] * 6
    cnpj_1 = array[1] * 7
    cnpj_2 = array[2] * 8
    cnpj_3 = array[3] * 9
    cnpj_4 = array[4] * 2
    cnpj_5 = array[5] * 3
    cnpj_6 = array[6] * 4
    cnpj_7 = array[7] * 5
    cnpj_8 = array[8] * 6
    cnpj_9 = array[9] * 7
    cnpj_10 = array[10] * 8
    cnpj_11 = array[11] * 9

    soma_d1 = cnpj_0 + cnpj_1 + cnpj_2 + cnpj_3 + cnpj_4 + cnpj_5 + cnpj_6 + cnpj_7 + cnpj_8 + cnpj_9 + cnpj_10 + cnpj_11

    multplica_d1 = soma_d1 % 11

    cnpj_0 = array[0] * 5
    cnpj_1 = array[1] * 6
    cnpj_2 = array[2] * 7
    cnpj_3 = array[3] * 8
    cnpj_4 = array[4] * 9
    cnpj_5 = array[5] * 2
    cnpj_6 = array[6] * 3
    cnpj_7 = array[7] * 4
    cnpj_8 = array[8] * 5
    cnpj_9 = array[9] * 6
    cnpj_10 = array[10] * 7
    cnpj_11 = array[11] * 8
    cnpj_12 = d1 * 9

    soma_d2 = cnpj_0 + cnpj_1 + cnpj_2 + cnpj_3 + cnpj_4 + cnpj_5 + cnpj_6 + cnpj_7 + cnpj_8 + cnpj_9 + cnpj_10 + cnpj_11 + cnpj_12

    multplica_d2 = soma_d2 % 11

    if (multplica_d1 == 10) {
      multplica_d1 = 0
    }
    if (multplica_d2 == 10) {
      multplica_d2 = 0
    }

    if (multplica_d1 != d1) {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "CNPJ não valido!"
      form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()

      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = ""
    }
    if (multplica_d2 != d2) {
      var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
      div.innerHTML = "CNPJ não valido!"
      form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()
      event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      var cpf_a = $('#cpf_reg')
      $.ajax({
        url: 'php/eng-verifica-cpf.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          "cpf_a": cpf_a.val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("VERIFICA CNPJ: " + data)

          if (data == "false") {
            var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
            div.innerHTML = "Este CNPJ ja esta sendo utilizado!"
            form_reg.cpf_reg.focus()
            event.preventDefault()
          } else {

          }
        },
        error: function(responseText) {
          console.log(responseText)
        }
      })
    }

  }

  if (telefone == "") {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "O telefone deve ser preenchido!"
    form_reg.tel_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""

  }
  if (telefone.length <= 12) {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "O telefone deve ser preenchido corretamente!"
    form_reg.tel_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
  if (endereco == "") {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "O endereço deve ser preenchido!"
    form_reg.end_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
  if (endereco.length <= 4) {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "O endereço deve ser preenchido corretamente!"
    form_reg.end_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
  if (estado == "") {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "O estado deve ser preenchido!"
    form_reg.esta_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
  if (estado.length == 1) {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "O estado deve ser preenchido!"
    form_reg.esta_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
  if (senha == "") {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "Senha deve ser preenchida!"
    form_reg.pass_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
  if (senha.length <= 7) {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "A senha deve conter no mínimo 8 digitos!"
    form_reg.pass_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
  if (confsenha == "") {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "Preencha o campo repita sua senha!"
    form_reg.confpass_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
  if (senha != confsenha) {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = "Senhas não conferem"
    form_reg.confpass_reg.focus()
    event.preventDefault()
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById("msgerro")
    div.innerHTML = ""
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <?php
  $titulo_page = "Cadastro - Ilhabela";
  require 'php/head.php'; 
 ?>
</head>

<body>
  <?php  
  require_once 'php/nav-home.php';
 ?>
  <div id="fundo-registro">
    <div class="container container-reg-form">
      <h1 class="titulo-index flow-text">
        ME CADASTRAR
      </h1>
      <div class="row row-reg-form fadeIn">
        <form class="col s12" method="post" name="form_reg" id="form_reg" action="php/eng-registro.php">
          <div id="msgerro">

          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input id="email" type="text" class="" name="email_reg" maxlength="50">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
              <label for="first_name">Nome Completo</label>
              <input id="pname_reg" type="text" class="validate" name="pname_reg" maxlength="60">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s4 c_doc">
              <div class="switch">
                <label>
         <span class="key-color-cpf color-blue">CPF</span>
             <input name="key_reg" value="0" type="checkbox" onchange="cpfCnpj()">
             <span class="lever"></span>
           <span class="key-color-cnpj">CNPJ</span>
        </label>
              </div>
              <input id="cpf_reg" type="text" class="validate" name="cpf_reg" maxlength="14" minlength="14">
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 n_doc">
              <label for="first_name">Número do documento</label>
              <input id="rg_reg" type="text" class="validate" name="rg_reg" maxlength="13" minlength="13">
            </div>
            <div class="col s2 t_doc">
              <label for="first_name">Tipo DOC</label>
              <select name="tipo_doc">
                <option value="RG">RG</option>
                <option value="CNH">CNH</option>
                <option value="CTPS">CTPS</option>
                <option value="Outro">Outro</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col s2 e_doc">
              <label for="first_name">Emissor</label>
              <input id="emi_reg" type="text" class="validate" name="emi_reg" maxlength="4" minlength="2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col s3">
              <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
              <input id="tel_reg" type="text" class="validate" name="tel_reg" maxlength="25">
            </div>
            <div class=" col s7">
              <label for="cndereco">Endereço</label>
              <input id="end_reg" type="text" class="validate" name="end_reg" maxlength="50">
            </div>
            <div class=" col s2">
              <label for="cndereco">Estado</label>
              <select name="esta_reg">
                <option value="SP">SP</option>
                <option value="AC">AC</option>
                <option value="AL">AL</option>
                <option value="AP">AP</option>
                <option value="AM">AM</option>
                <option value="BA">BA</option>
                <option value="CE">CE</option>
                <option value="DF">DF</option>
                <option value="ES">EP</option>
                <option value="GO">GO</option>
                <option value="MA">MA</option>
                <option value="MT">MT</option>
                <option value="MS">MS</option>
                <option value="MG">MG</option>
                <option value="PA">PA</option>
                <option value="PB">PB</option>
                <option value="PR">PR</option>
                <option value="PE">PE</option>
                <option value="PI">PI</option>
                <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
                <option value="RN">RN</option>
                <option value="RS">RS</option>
                <option value="RO">RO</option>
                <option value="RR">RR</option>
                <option value="SC">SC</option>
                <option value="SE">SE</option>
                <option value="TO">TO</option>
                <option value="EX">Estrangeiro</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col s4">
              <label for="password">Senha</label>
              <input id="password" type="password" class="validate" name="pass_reg" maxlength="25">
            </div>
            <div class=" col s4">
              <label for="password">Repita a senha</label>
              <input id="confpassword" type="password" class="validate" name="confpass_reg" maxlength="25">
            </div>

            <div class="col s4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn" value="cadastrar" style="width: 100%; padding: 0; height: 70px;">
       CADASTRAR</button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php  
  require 'php/footer.php';
 ?>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/eng-registro.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: podes mostrar a função dentro da qual esse ajax corre e a maneira como o `form` é submetido?

Comment: O `.preventDefault()` é para cancelar um evento cancelável. Seu código não mostra nenhuma chamada de evento. Provavelmente deve estar querendo cancelar um submit. Se for isso, o `.preventDefault()` deve estar na função do evento e não no AJAX.

Comment: Eu estou chamando la em cima o evento "form_cadastrar.onsubmit = function(event)" ate msm que se n estivesse chamando n funcionaria .preventDefault() com o noem em branco. Só  n consegui colocar o código inteiro aqui

Comment: Coloca o código aqui que nós ajudamos a formatar

Comment: Minhas desculpas, sou novo neste forum

Comment: Ajax é assincrono, não tem como interromper um evento que já ocorreu, leia mais em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/3635

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, não sei exatamente se pode ser chamado "gambiarra", mas a questão é que .preventDefault() definitivamente não funciona dentro do ajax, não sei exatamente pq, mas nem "return false" funciona. Oq eu conclui depois de uma semana com esse problema:

Se eu não consigo parar o avanço da pagina dentro ajax, mas consigo mostrar a mensagem de erro dentro da DIV com o ID:msgerro, consigo verificar o valor dentro da DIV, se a mensagem for == a "Este email já está sendo utilizado" event.preventDefault(). Segue o código:

```
''' var erro_json = $('#msgerro').html() //puxa valor da DIV
''' if (erro_json == "Este email já está sendo utilizado!") {
'''  event.preventDefault()
''' }
```