# O Axios usa AJAX por default?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

Pessoa, uma dúvida ao estudar axios me surgiu. Quando utilizo a call http padrão com axios.get(url).then(), isso já é considerado como uma chamada AJAX? Ou é necessário adicionar algo a mais?

Comment: Um AJAX é uma requisição feita por JavaScript de forma assíncrona, portanto, sim, a requisição utilizando a API do `axios` é uma forma de AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em navegadores é sim, por padrão ele usa o [`XmlHttpRequest` (vulgo ajax)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116177/3635), pode conferir no código fonte:

- https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/6642ca9aa1efae47b1a9d3ce3adc98416318661c/lib/defaults.js#L18

Mas se for "back-end" (dentro do `node.js`) vai usar as seguintes libs:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var httpFollow = require('follow-redirects').http;
var httpsFollow = require('follow-redirects').https;
var url = require('url');
var zlib = require('zlib');
```

Vale lembrar que você pode criar o seu próprio "adaptador" No entanto você pode trocar o "adaptador" dessa forma:

```
var settle = require('./../core/settle');

module.exports = function myAdapter(config) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  
    var response = {
      data: responseData,
      status: request.status,
      statusText: request.statusText,
      headers: responseHeaders,
      config: config,
      request: request
    };

    settle(resolve, reject, response);

  });
}
```

Podendo aplicar até a [**API `fetch()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), ou pode resolver aplicando assim também:

```
axios({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    ...
    adapter: function (config) {
        seu adaptador aqui dentro
    }
});
```

Ou então pode aplicar GLOBALMENTE:

```
axios.defaults.adapter = function () {
    seu adptador aqui dentro
};
```