# Inserir valor javascript atraves de variavel php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso inserir valor width e height através de uma variável php.

```
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var image = document.querySelector('#image'); 
            var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                ready: function () {
                    this.cropper.setCropBoxData({
      "left":750,
      "top":190,
      "width":500,
      "height":50
    });    
  },
});
```

A onde :

```
"width":100,
"height":50
```

Ficaria por exemplo:

```
"width": $VALOR,
"height":$VALOR2
```

Porém dessa forma não funciona,

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: PHP <-> HTML, HTML <-> JS, JS x-x PHP !

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51392/ler-os-dados-do-php-no-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o arquivo com o seu código estiver dentro de uma tag `<script>` em um arquivo com a extensão .php, você poderá fazer assim:

```
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var image = document.querySelector('#image'); 
            var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                ready: function () {
                    this.cropper.setCropBoxData({
      "left":750,
      "top":190,
      "width": <?= $width; ?>,
      "height": <?= $height; ?>
    });    
  },
});
```

Se este código javascript estiver dentro de um arquivo com a extensão .js infelizmente não tem como.

Comment: Funcinou da seguinte forma : <?= $valor->width ?> , Obrigado!

Comment: então essa variável $valor era um objeto?

Comment: Não, porém vou utilizar dessa forma e crias as function para realizar a consulta no banco de dados, muito obrigado!